# al momento de hacer un post desde codeigniter 4 hasta la base de datos utilizando ajax y jquery me sale error 500

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-4

este es el error: jquery-3.3.1.js:9600
POST http://localhost:8080/temporalCompra/insertar/2/1/65a80f60b6676 500 (Internal Server Error)
send    @   jquery-3.3.1.js:9600
ajax    @   jquery-3.3.1.js:9206
agregarProducto @   nuevo:279
onclick @   nuevo:193

esta es la funcion :
function agregarProducto(id_producto, cantidad, id_compra) {

```
        if (id_producto != null && id_producto !=0 && cantidad > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url();?>temporalCompra/insertar/'+ id_producto + "/" +
                    cantidad + "/" + id_compra,
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}, 

                success: function(resultado) {
                    if (resultado == 0) {

                    } else {
                        /*

                        $("#resultado_error").html(resultado.error);

                        if (resultado.existe) {
                            $("#id_producto").val(resultado.datos.id);
                            $("#nombre").val(resultado.datos.nombre);
                            $("#cantidad").val(1);
                            $("#precio_compra").val(resultado.datos.precio_compra);
                            $("#Subtotal").val(resultado.datos.precio_compra);
                            $("#cantidad").focus();
                        } else {
                            $("#id_producto").val('');
                            $("#nombre").val('');
                            $("#cantidad").val('');
                            $("#precio_compra").val('');
                            $("#Subtotal").val('');

                        } */
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

y esta el boton:

`class="btn btn-primary" onclick="agregarProducto(id_producto.value, cantidad.value,
                         '<?php echo $id_compra; ?>' )">
                         Agregar Producto</button>
                    </div>`

Comment: El error 500 es un error en el código de tu servidor, porque lo que tiene poca relación con el código cliente que has puesto en tu pregunta